# Set numpy.ndarray values to a scalar

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I´ve an variable that´s a numpy array:

```
(Pdb) type(inFile.z)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(Pdb) 
(Pdb) print inFile.z
[-0.188 -0.109 -0.02  ...,  0.373  0.356  0.385]
(Pdb)
```

Id´like to set all values to 20. I tried:

```
inFile.z[:]=20
inFile.z.fill(20)
```

But it doesn´t works, that is, the values reamains the same.

How can I do that?

Comment: This might happen if `inFile.z` is a property. What is `type(inFile).z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill works. Give more background on what inFile is and/or try making sure you're libs are up to date.

```
In [3]: x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [4]: x
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [5]: type(x)
Out[5]: numpy.ndarray

In [6]: x.f
x.fill     x.flags    x.flat     x.flatten

In [6]: x.fill('boo')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b4528b13e992> in <module>()
----> 1 x.fill('boo')

ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'boo'

In [7]: x.fill('1')

In [8]: x
Out[8]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [10]: x.fill(2.5342)

In [11]: x
Out[11]: array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: You´re right, it´s about laspy. If I do:

z=inFile.z
z.fill(0)

It works.

Comment: Please check off the answer to close it.